# Not able to install Windows 10 on oracle virtual box

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-10-preview

I have installed ORACLE virtual box in Windows 7 machine and created a VM for windows10 technical preview with the following settings:

**Guest:**
iso:  Windows10_TechnicalPreview_x64_EN-US_9926
Machine Version:  Windows 8.1 64-bit
Storage Type:  VDI, 40GB, fixed storage
Enabled EFI
Enabled PAE/NX
Virtual Box version: 4.3.2

**Host Machine:**
Windows 7
Intel i7, 64-bit

If I start the virtual machine, it is not able to get the windows Install screen. It keeps on waiting at the windows logo.
After some time, it is giving EFI screen as shown below.

[image: EFI screen]

I enter exit and select continue. But there is no hope.

After waiting for long time, it went to recovery screen shown below.
[image: Recovery Screen]

Comment: code 0xc0000225 means ERROR_INSTRUCTION_MISALIGNMENT: An attempt was made to execute an instruction at an unaligned address and the host system does not support unaligned instruction references. Which Intel CPU do you have?

Comment: Intel(R) Core (TM) i7-2600 CPU @3.40Hz.  Note: If I install new version of Virtual box, then the VMs wont boot up.

Comment: ask this in their forum: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewforum.php?f=2

Answer (score 0):

Windows10_TechnicalPreview_x64_EN-US_9926 x64 seems to behave strangely while installing.
On my first attempt of installing it, it stopped because it could not copy a file (no skip option).
Then I tested the x86 version and it worked. Then I retried the x64 version and it worked.

What you could try at this point is to use UEFI backwards compatibility (good old BIOS mode).

Comment: Hi Overmind, how use UEFI backward compatibility. I didn't see any setting in virtual box for backward compatibility.

Comment: It suppose to let you selected (or not) the EFI option in Virtualbox for a 64 bit install. But VirtualBox tends to forget its "NVRAM" settings when you reboot. Anyway, to switch to BIOS mode, run VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --firmware bios   ; Also note that 4.3 update fixes some UEFI-related booting issues on windows.

Comment: If I use BIOS mode, It goes to Recovery Screen directly and informs m e "PC is running into ISSUES".. If I use latest version of virtual box, no VM is starting (even the old machines or any new linux machine I have created)

Comment: If you switched from EFI to BIOS or backwards you need to clean the target installation drive, or simply delete and recreate it, and make sure it actually boots from the installation kit, not the target drive.

Answer (score 0):

This error was fixed for me by enabling "I/O APIC".

Go to **Settings > System > Motherboard :** check the "**Enable I/O APIC**" box.

Answer (score -1):

I have installed the same Windows10_TechnicalPreview_x64_EN-US_9926.iso in my VirtualBox running on Windows 7 (x64). My settings:
**Guest:**

iso: Windows10_TechnicalPreview_x64_EN-US_9926
Machine Version: Windows 2012 (64 bit)
Storage Type: VDI, 20GB, fixed storage
Disabled EFI
Disabled PAE/NX
Virtual Box version: 4.3.2

**Host Machine:**

Windows 7
Intel i5, 64-bit

Comment: I will try using Windows 2012 (64 bit)

Comment: Sorry, This configuration didn't work for me.

Comment: But I failed to mention that I tried 2-3 times installing it.. It was either getting stuck in setup or while restarting after setting up.